# Using FakeItEasy, is there a way to fake the setter of a write only property?

Tags: c#, fakeiteasy

Using FakeItEasy, is there a way to fake the setter of a write only property?

The interface I have to work with looks something like:

```
Interface IMyInterface
{
   String Foo { set; }
}
```

I have tried the following but the syntax doesn't work.

```
IMyInterface _myObject = A.Fake<IMyInterface>();
A.CallTo(() => _myObject.Foo).Invokes((String foo) => {
   //save off foo
});
```

I have also tried this, but syntax error.

```
IMyInterface _myObject = A.Fake<IMyInterface>();
A.CallTo(() => _myObject.set_Foo).Invokes((String foo) => {
   //save off foo
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it, but it's not very straightforward, due to a limitation of expression trees (you can't write an assignment in an expression). The workaround is to use the "advanced" call configuration syntax (described [in the docs](http://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/specifying-a-call-to-configure/#specifying-a-call-to-any-method-or-property)):

```
A.CallTo(_myObject)
 .Where(call => call.Method.Name == "set_Foo")
 .Invokes((String foo) => {
   //save off foo
 });
```

That being said, having a write-only property is probably not a very good idea; if you can set it, you should be able to get it too. If you really want it to be write-only, consider using a method rather than a property.

Comment: I agree with your assessment of a write only property as well.  In this case, it really should be a method, but I cannot change it.

Answer (score 4):

FakeItEasy added a method to handle this case, `A.CallToSet`

```
IMyInterface _myObject = A.Fake<IMyInterface>();

// Variant 1
A.CallToSet(() => _myObject.Foo).Invokes(call => {
   var foo = call.GetArgument<string>(0);
   // save off foo
});

// Variant 2
A.CallToSet(() => _myObject.Foo).Invokes((string foo) => {
   // save off foo
});
```

Comment: I don't think this works; a get-less property just won't convert to `Expression<Func<T>>`.